# Quadratic formula and isolating $f(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, education

> $f(x) - \frac{1}{f(x)} = g(x)$

I need to isolate $f(x)$. So far I got

> $f(x)f(x) - g(x)f(x) - 1 = 0$

Now I've tried to use the quadratic root formula with no success..
What should I do?

Comment: If $ax^2+bx+c=0$ then $x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. In your case $a=1, b=-g(x), c =1$ Also there is a mistake: not $f(x)f(x)-g(x)f(x)-1=0$, but $f(x)f(x)-g(x)f(x)+1=0$

Comment: Name $f(x)=X$ and $g(x)=a$ and solve the quadratic in $X$. Later, replace $X$ by $f(x)$ and $a$ by $g(x)$

Comment: @Deltaspace Sorry I edited, the initial equation had a minus in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments indicated, replace $f(x)$ by $X$ and $g(x)$ by $a$. So we have to solve
$$X-\frac{1}{X}=a$$
Multiplying both sides by $X$, we get
$$X^2-1=aX$$
Using the quadratic formula, we get
$$X=\frac{a\pm\sqrt{a^2+4}}{2}$$
So
$$f(x)=\frac{g(x)\pm\sqrt{g(x)^2+4}}{2}$$

Comment: You didn't replace second $a$ in last line.

Comment: @Deltaspace oh yes, sorry. I corrected it.